# How to select a column value based on another column value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
   ---------------
    1   a   0   1
    2   4   0   3
    3   a   0   4
    4   a   4   5
    5   t   3   9
```

I would like to fetch out the column `C` alone,whenever the value in `A` is `a`.

So I should get :

```
C
--
0
0
4
```

How to get it done?

Comment: Use `df = df.loc[df.B == 'a', ['C']]`

Comment: Yep, you can create a view with `df = df.loc[<boolean array>,  [columns names]]`.